# How to get stuck hot water shut off to close?

Tags: faucet, shutoff, stuck

I’m trying to change my bathroom sink faucet and the cold water shut off closed easily. The hot water one I can not get for the life of me.

I’ve tried WD40 and I tried a hair dryer. I tried tapping it with my pliers but I’m scared to break it so no movement. How do I get it to close? Is this a sign it’s busted and needs to be replaced?

Comment: Think it might be time for replacement.  They are not expensive.  Turn off the hot valve at the hot water tank or the main water shut off valve.  Open the hot faucet to reduce pressure and then can replace the valve.  Usually faster than trying to fix.

Comment: you can try torquing the heck out of it with two wrenches, something will give. If it fails, replace, if not, might want to replace anyway, a ball valve is better.

Comment: can we see it (pic)

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself the heartache of messing around with the shutoff and go straight to replacing it. (There’s a 99% chance you’d have to do it anyway.)

I like 1/4 turn units with metal internals.